# Subdomain wildcard within graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the count of likes a link has on Facebook and can get that working fine however, the links are given subdomains on Facebook when posting the link so for example:

[http://history.viralthread.com/post-slug](http://www.viralthread.com/post-slug)

But on the main website where the count will be requested the url is

http://www.viralthread.com/post-slug

So for example:
[image: Example]

So Ideally I need to get the total likes for the url no matter what subdomain is used. I cannot find a way of using a wildcard for the subdomain.

Comment: They are different links so Facebook will treat them as different links

Comment: You should specify _one_ distinct `og:url` meta tag value; that way Facebook will see both as the same object.